# Leafletjs How to project EPSG4326 points to the leaflet default

Tags: leaflet

I am using Australian government map data found here: [Victoria, Australia locality data](https://data.gov.au/geoserver/vic-suburb-locality-boundaries-psma-administrative-boundaries/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=ckan_af33dd8c_0534_4e18_9245_fc64440f742e&outputFormat=json), which is provided in the EPSG4326 projection.

When I try to use the data with leaflet, of course, my data is a bit distorted due to the earth's curvature - so my data is not represented properly on the screen because the maps are using a different projection to my data.

I have tried to force the map to use EPSG4326 by setting it in Map options and also in the TileLayer, as shown here:

```
var gisLayer = L.tileLayer(
  'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    //subdomains: ['0', '1', '2', '3'],
    attribution: 'openstreetmap',
    reuseTiles: true,
    updateWhenIdle: false,
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326
});

var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [-28.5, 135.575],
  zoom: 4
  ,crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326
});

map.addLayer(gisLayer);
```

but when I do this, the maps do not display. I don't believe the map tiles have been generated for this projection. That said, there is a suggestion in the docos [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#crs) that it might be possible, but I couldn't get this working. (Did I just get the configuration wrong?)

It seemed like it was working when I retrieved the data and placed it on the map, but when I got the map bounds to select the data for the visible region, it also showed distorted. So I tried to convert the map bounds to EPSG4326 manually, to pass that to the database, as follows:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var coords4326_NE = L.Projection.SphericalMercator.unproject(bounds._northEast);
console.log(coords4326_NE);
```

but that broke the code. I was passing the wrong structure in and I couldn't get this right either.

Of course, I would also accept transforming every point returned from the database to the default projection, which I think is EPSG3857. But I am having doing this as well.

I have provided as jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tonywr/xjno769q/13/) where I have been attempting to do the above.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GeoJSON data is encoded in WGS84, which can be simply plotted on EPSG4326, but is also the expected input for EPSG3857 ([Web Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator)).

From that Wikipedia article:

> While the Web Mercator's formulas are for the spherical form of the Mercator, geographical coordinates are required to be in the WGS 84 ellipsoidal datum.

Therefore, you do not have to change anything to plot your data onto a *regular* Leaflet map, using *regular* tiles (from OSM or Mapbox, which provide tiles only for EPSG3857).

[image: Screenshot of OP's data onto a regular Leaflet map]

Comment: Ok, so I think you're saying that it doesn't matter because the points are all longitude and latitude and will still plot successfully on the map. But as I am loading deltas of data, I need to be able to retrieve data from the database only within the bounds of the visible viewport. I believe leaflet provides the viewport bounds in EPSG3857, so how can I convert this to EPSG4326 so that I can intersect and get the right data from the database?

Comment: "I am loading deltas of data": this sounds like a different feature. Please feel free to open a new question with relevant details and code. As for bounds of viewport, same story: Leaflet will provide you with lat and lng, i.e. WGS84. Furthermore, it sounds like you are trying to retrieve data from a WFS service. There should be plenty resources on that topic, including here on SO and on GIS Stack Exchange.